# PHP/Python bizarre behavior

Tags: php, python, html, raspberry-pi

I cant get my head around why it works with a different file and it doesn't with the shared file. Any hero who can solve this mystery would be my champion.

So this is what I'm trying to do, A PHP scrip writes data to a file. Either 0,1, or -1. The same text file is read from a python scrip and makes a servo motor move left or right based on the -1 or 1 and 0 for nothing. If I create a dummy text file my self and make the python read it, it works like a charm, but when I make the python script read the PHP modified text file it does print the value in the console but the servo doesn't move!!! I don't know if there is a read/write mayhem or the way the 0 and 1 is being written. Here is the code.

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

if ($_POST['leftb'])           
{ echo "Left is pressed";      // If Left button is pressed
    $txt = -1;}                // Set txt to -1


else if ($_POST['rightb'])
{ echo "Right is pressed";     // If Right button is pressed
    $txt = 1;}                 // Set txt to 1


fwrite($myfile, $txt);        // Write the value to file
fclose($myfile);              // Close file



sleep(1);                     // Wait 1 second

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = 0;                     // Reset previous value to 0
fwrite($myfile, $txt);        // Write to the same file
fclose($myfile);              // Close the file

?>
```

Python Script:

```
# System initialization on Raspberry Pi 3
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
initial = 5
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(38,GPIO.OUT)
pwm=GPIO.PWM(38,50)

# Set the servo position in the middle (5)
pwm.start(5)
position = initial

while True:

    f = open("newfile.txt","r")    # Read file written by PHP for value
    x = f.read();
    x = int(x)                     # Make sure its an integer value

    position = position + x        # Increment or decrement initial position 


    if position != initial:        # If position is different from initial position, update the servo position
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
        print position         # Print to screen the current servo position

    else: 
        pwm.stop()             # If no new position detected, stop the servo


        f.close()              # Close the text file 
    time.sleep(0.8)
```

As you can see, a common text file is shared between the two programs. The name of the file is "newfile.txt". I can manually see the data being written by the php scrip when I open it or simply see the output of the python on the terminal, only that it doesn't actually rotate the servo. The same thing would work if I made a new text file and manually wrote -1 or 1 or 0 and the servo would perfectly move.

I cant understand why the same -1 or 1 in two text files different from each other? Is one character and other integer? I really can use help!

Comment: I blame newlines. Post `cat -vet newfile.txt`

Comment: No clue what you meant there, can you kindly please elaborate what you meant? Thanks @bishop

Comment: My guess is, the line endings of the file when edited vs. when created by PHP are inconsistent and your program doesn't handle that. `cat` is a command on UNIX machines. `-vet` argument works on GNU/Linux machines to show unprintable characters in the file. If you don't have that, then I'd suggest using a program that can show you the actual bytes in the file and double check the line endings (and that you have no stray, non-printing characters).

Comment: Oh I now get what u mean, Both the programs are running on the Raspberry Pi. So as you are suggesting I add the -vet command before the newfile.txt? As in when writing or opening or closing?

Comment: But also the question remains, how is python able to print out the values perfectly in the terminal? Its even adding them and subtracting them! If there was something going wrong they wouldn't be showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check that both file have the same encoding e.g. (ASCII vs Unicode)?